# Validation causing error

Tags: python, linux, exception, tkinter, tuples

When running the following function:

```
def RestoreSelection(self, selectedItems):
    self.RecvList.selection_clear(0,"end")
    items = self.RecvList.get(0,"end")
    for item in selectedItems:
        for _i in items:
         if item[:6] == _i[:6]:
            index = items.index(item)
            print index
            self.RecvList.selection_set(index)
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1437, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 498, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "./pycan1.8.py", line 710, in RecvBtn_Click
    self.RestoreSelection(selected)
  File "./pycan1.8.py", line 443, in RestoreSelection
    index = items.index(item)
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
```

Unfortunately the error message isn't terribly clear. Could someone please explain what this error message is? and what is causing the function to produce it.

This only happened once I put the nested for loop in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that value which index you are trying to find in the `items` tuple does not exist in this tuple.

```
>>> a = (1,2)
>>> a.index(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
```

To avoid that you can wrap lines where you trying to get an index into `try\except` block, like:

```
def RestoreSelection(self, selectedItems):
    self.RecvList.selection_clear(0,"end")
    items = self.RecvList.get(0,"end")
    for item in selectedItems:
        for _i in items:
         if item[:6] == _i[:6]:
            try:
                index = items.index(item)
            except ValueError:
                index = None #set default value here
            print index
            self.RecvList.selection_set(index)
```